# how to convert wechat official account articles with images to pdf

Tags: python-3.x, pdfkit, wechat

for general html, when use pdfkit to convert html to pdf,images in the html can be saved in pdf.

while for wechat official account articles, I found images in urls was lost. the following code is an instance.

how to save wechat official account articles with images to pdf?

```
import pdfkit
url='https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s?__biz=MzA3NDMyOTcxMQ==&mid=2651249314&idx=1&sn=5338576a80a4145b9808ff06cc980c14'
path_wkthmltopdf = 'C:/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe'
pdfkit.from_url(url=url,output_path='c:/test.pdf',configuration=pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkthmltopdf))'
```

I think one of the solution is rolling down the url to load all images, then convert it to pdf. how to rolling down to load all images in pdfkit?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work without modifying the windows environment variables:

```
import pdfkit
path_wkthmltopdf = r'C:\Python27\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkthmltopdf)
url = 'https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s?timestamp=1515570589&src=3&ver=1&signature=xsZdozV1JPS2K8SuXJ8TKeqfuczP2z78*LCVu32ljt1NSa8oF41X88W0JYguTbLUwHHyt0ksUy8l9ljM5*uGOSH-GBjlVipz4a1aIeg9xNQgwlxuCV*9dURcg-U8UvR78C2RV6B5CIeA0n1jIaiFiqrQTIuel5IW-HYAcQsOT0g='
pdfkit.from_url(url, "out.pdf", configuration=config)
```

Assuming the path is correct (e.g. in my case it is r'C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe').

Result:

```
Loading page (1/2)
Printing pages (2/2)                                               
Done
```

PDF [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxdvwjn9vf0lfuf/out.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: it's not the problem of path_wkthmltopdf, I can download the page of google.com with pictures, can you try the url I provided? thanks

Comment: with above code, I am able to download the pdf file with specifying your URL.

Comment: including pictures in url?

Comment: This website having some issue due to that Image not getting loaded. [Error Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i8kaxjdnnhefo32/Screenshotfrom2018-01-1017-54-54.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: sorry, I update the url, please try this. [https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s?__biz=MzA3NDMyOTcxMQ==&mid=2651249314&idx=1&sn=5338576a80a4145b9808ff06cc980c14

Comment: @Renke did you find a solution? If so, please share. Thanks!